# Check if $_REQUEST url exists in database

Tags: php

I'm using `$id = intval( $_REQUEST['id'] );` , to get ID of the news/posts on my website, and the link to the news is article.php?id=XXX. So when someone type ?id=1 and there's nothing it's empty, no posts, it should go to index page (index.php) instead showing blank page. Is it possible? I've tried via isset something but it didn't worked. Can anyone help me with this, please.

```
if($ArticleSQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id' ")){
...
}
```

Comment: `else {header("Location: /");}`

Comment: Also take care: you implement a sql injection vulnerabilty here. You want to fix that using the advantages of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" that `mysqli` offers (hint: `id='$id'` is _really_ evil...).

Comment: I guess you have some options. First: Check if get `isset($_GET['id'])` exists if not, use `header("Location: index.php")`. Second: Send the **id** by **POST**, but isn't a good choice. Third: Check if u get any return from your **db**, if not use `header("Location: index.php")`.

Comment: @arkascha I'm learning, I don't really know to use prepared statements yet, but I read that if it's only number it cant be SQL injected.

Comment: And who prevents Mr. Evil to type `...?id=my_evil_code` instead of a "number"?

Comment: I'm trying prepared statements, but I always make mistake. I know it can be SQL injected, and that prepared statements are good against injections. I have a lot to learn about that. I'm reading php.net about that, I'll try to make something again, but I don't really understand examples they're showing. You can know that I'm new, just because I didn't know use num_rows. Anyway thank you, every help is good.

Comment: @arkascha I agree with adding more typical SQL injection prevention, but the OP is using [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to make sure the input is a number/int. It's no typical solution, but I'd say the OP is aware of the threat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the number of results with `$ArticleSQL->num_rows`.

So your code will now be:

```
$ArticleSQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id' ");

if($ArticleSQL->num_rows > 0) {
    $article = $ArticleSQL->fetch_array();

    //show the article here

} else {

    //redirection:
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the query found anything. Your code simply checks if the query succeeded. A query which returns no rows is **NOT** a failure. It's a perfectly valid result set that happens to have no rows in it.

```
$result = $mysqli->query(...);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ... found something ... }
```